# Facebook connect in android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an android app that uses facebook connect for users to log in, however, it is working fine when debugging but after uploading the app in the market facebook connect is not working and it shows login failed message , how to solve please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload the app into Market, you're using a different certificate to sign the apk files than the one you used when developing.

You need to change the Android Key Hash in the Mobile Settings of the Facebook application to reflect the certificate used to publish the app in Android Market.